# PHP warning expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given

Tags: php, sql

I want to retrieve all data from a table, so I use this code

```
<?php
    include("config.php");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$USERS;
    $sql_result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    if ($sql_result) {
      while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
         echo $result;
       }
    } 
    else {
       die ('Could not execute SQL query '.$sql);
    }
?>
```

but got this warning:

```
 Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
 object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\newSDP\phpscript\users.php on line 6
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: You can't mix and match mysql_* and mysqli_* functions.

Comment: use mysqli_fetch_assoc() function instead of mysql_fetch_assoc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:
mysql_fetch_assoc  to mysqli_fetch_assoc

Comment: I agree with @arkascha. At least give Jon Stirling or Bhaskar credit for the answer.

Comment: maybe @Bhaskar should have pasted it as an answer not a comment is he/she was sure.

Comment: Well no credit is needed here since it's too damn obvious why they get the error. That's why I also downvoted the question

Comment: Although the time stamp on Jon Stirlings comment says (currently) 17 minutes ago, and the timestamp on this answer says 16 minutes ago. So it looks like this answer came first.. Just saying...

Comment: It is obvious to you does make it obvious to everyone, I am not a PHP developer, I use other languages with mongoDB, You see you are one of the reasons I don't care much if I get a down vote so far I get the ans I need. And tnks gabs for the ans it was what I needed, Plus @superphonic tnks for noting that. So everyone else pls before you show your self an asshole try to make sure you check the time stamp on the ans. Tnk u :-).